# Google Maps SDK iOS - Custom marker info window with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an iOS project which shows map with pinned locations. When user taps on a location an Custom Info window is shown with some details. I use the below method to

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

The custom info window has a set of labels & buttons. As of now everything is working perfectly except that the IBOutlet of the UIButton in the custom info window is not firing. Its like Google Maps is rendering the custom info window as an image.

Is there any way where i can have buttons inside of it and have Touch Up inside fired?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an UIButton in a info window, it's a snapshot of the UIView, what you can do, is create an UItapGesture recognizer or use another delegade didTapInfoWindowOfMarker

for more info:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#ae1614978aef680d671a6a95da8e13bf7

here's a free course:

http://googlemaps.codeschool.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right, the info window **is** rendered as a flattened view.

Please see the grey-boxed note on the developers page regarding Info Windows.

- iOS

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#info_windows

- And for completeness, the same is true for the Android SDK

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows

I've had this problem myself, there is no (sane) way around it. Unfortunately, you'll have to redesign what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I guess i have to take the unfortunate side. :( I had to implement it at all costs. Where do i start if i need to redesign? Or i was thinking like if mapView:markerInfoWindow gives a (x,y) position of the touched location we can map with the button's rectangle and see if it matches? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You 'could' slap a view over the top of the map, catching screen coordinates of touch events and propagating them down to the map - then using those coords to superimpose your own fake popup over the map - but I highly highly suggest you don't. Google Maps is a tool provided to us with an intended use, if you need controls so badly in the context a particular marker, i suggest having a separate view below the map with contextual buttons. You can update them with a callback from the marker touched events. I have done this myself before.